# Angular form one character behind in updating value (Odd behaviour)

Tags: angular, user-input, angular-forms, form-control, formgroups

I am new to Angular, but I have been trying my best to learn as much as possible. Currently, I am working on making a form using FormGroup and FormControl, but there seems to be something very odd happening. When I try to enter a value or update the value in the text field, the FormGroup component "odometerReader" updates the value and remains  1 character behind. It have attached a link in the bottom. I am puzzled and unable to debug this . Is there anyone who has gone through this ?

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iec4x.gif)

### HTML File

```
    <form
        #form="ngForm"
        [formGroup]="odometerForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" 
        >
        <div class="fieldset field-container"
            [ngClass]="{'fieldset--invalid fieldset--invalid-without-warning-icon': (odometerReader.invalid || odometerReader.value == null) && form.submitted}">
            <input class="input input__suffix"
                data-piiexclude
                formControlName="odometerReader"
                maxlength="7"
                max="9999999"
                min="0"
                placeholder="Ex: 10000"
                type="number"/>
            <div class="input-suffix">Km</div>

            <div class="fieldset__error-message" *ngIf = "(odometerReader.invalid || odometerReader.value == null) && form.submitted">
                Please enter an odometer reading and select 'Next', otherwise select 'Unsure' to continue.
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

### My Component

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private seo: SeoService,
    private journeyService: JourneyService
) {
    this.seo.setPageTitle(pageName);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.odometerForm = new FormGroup({
        odometerReader: new FormControl(
            getStoredOdometer(),{
                validators:[
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.min(0),
                    Validators.max(9999999)
                ]
        })
    });
}
```

---

### Angular version in my system

| Package | version |
| --- | --- |
| @angular-devkit/architect | 0.1102.1 |
| @angular-devkit/build-angular | 0.1102.1 |
| @angular-devkit/core | 11.2.1 |
| @angular-devkit/schematics | 11.2.1 |
| @angular/localize | 11.2.0 |
| @schematics/angular | 11.2.1 |
| @schematics/update | 0.1102.1 |
| ng-packagr | 11.2.2 |
| rxjs | 6.6.3 |
| typescript | 4.0.5 |

Comment: Can you share  data-piiexclude directive code?

Comment: yeah sure , I would have to search but let me check

Comment: You can add [(ngModel)] value to input field, like `[(ngModel)]="inputValue"`, initialize the value like `inputValue: string = null` and in input field also add (ngModelChange) like `(ngModelChange)="inputChanged($event)"` so your log in `inputChanged(text:string)` method will return actual value of the input changes on runtime.

Comment: @Chellappanவ I did not find the code but I did remove data-piiexude and run the project but still it has the same issue

Comment: @MishaMashina The thing is I need to use the Validators in the formGroup for the validation , Its a requirement for me. Is there anyway I can use Validators outside the form ?

Comment: If it possible can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I am sorry , I cannot put the project in stackblitz , the project is confidential